# Alternating rows starting with image

Tags: html, css

Please can someone help.

I need to make each of my rows alternate between image and text. So row 1 will start with an image then text next to it, row 2 starts with text then image next to it, row 3 will start with an image then text next to it and so on.

I am busy changing a static site to wordpress.

Comment: Share your code

Comment: And what's exactly the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css element `:nth-child()`.

```
tr:nth-child(odd) {
    float: left;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    float: right;
}
```